# Regex of function call code

Tags: java, regex

I've strings like

```
con(tRegionDefaults.committee_chairman,', Secretary & Treasurer')
con('Non-Voting Member - ',tRegionDefaults.corptypelong,' Manager')
con('Vice ',tRegionDefaults.committee_chairman)
```

Tried to make a regex for getting all function parameters from each of the examples (including single quotes where the argument is a string), however with no success.

What I came upon was this regex but it doesn't give me groups of the function parameters:

```
([\(])([^,]+)+(\))
```

Can anyone give hint how to do that?

Comment: Unless you need to allow nested parentheses, just get everything from `(` to `)`. If you have to allow nested parentheses, you need to write a real parser, regular expressions are not the right tool.

Comment: @Barmar added a regex I tried

Comment: A regexp can't return a variable number of groups. You can't match each parameter in a different group.

Comment: If you follow a capture group with `+` or `*`, it just captures the first match.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to put `\(` inside `[]`.

Comment: @Barmar obviously my try of doing the stuff was wrong. Are you able to assist and at least share with me if it is possible to get the function parameters with a regex. Thank you

Comment: @mickmackusa Java

Comment: @mickmackusa it does perfect job, please post as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern:  `'[^']+'|(?<=con\(|,)[^,]+(?=,|\))`

Pattern Explanation:

```
'[^']+'  #Match substrings that are single quoted<br>

|        # or

(?<=con\(|,)[^,]+(?=,|\))  
#Match non-comma characters preceded by con( or comma AND followed by a comma or )
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the capture group around all the arguments, not a single argument.

```
\((.*)\)
```

It's not possible to get each argument in a separate capture group, unless you're willing to limit the number of arguments that you capture. Capture groups are determined statically from the regexp by counting the parentheses -- a capture group inside a repetition  quantifier still only captures one thing (its first match, I believe).

So use the above regexp to capture all the arguments, then use some other code to split the captured text at `,` characters.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The tricky part is that there are commas inside of the string parameters too, and that makes it difficult to parse